# Laravel project bitbucket pipeline uses .env.testing instead of .env.pipeline

Tags: laravel, bitbucket-pipelines

I have adopted bitbucket's CI/CD pipeline for my laravel project. Laravel versoin 8*.

According to the bitbucket documentation and community example, I have added a .env.pipeline file in the repo. Here is the snippet from the yml file:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Build and push the image
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - apk update && apk add mysql-client
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer install --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
            - cp .env.pipeline .env
            - php artisan key:generate
            - php artisan config:clear
            - php artisan migrate
            - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
          services:
            - mysql
```

The repo also has a `.env.testing` file as well as a `phpunit.xml` file. This is the contents fo the phpunit.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
        <report>
            <clover outputFile="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
            <html outputDirectory="build/coverage"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testing"/>
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Locally the unit tests run and pass. But in the pipeline, the process fails complaining about mysql host cannot be resolved. Upon troubleshooting I found that the value of `DB_HOST` value was not what it is set in the .env.pipeline file, rather the value is being picked up from .env.testing file. That is why mysql host could not be resovled by the pipeline process.

What I do not understand is for unit tests in the pipeline, what is the point of having the `.env.pipeline` file if that file is not going to be used when a `.env.testing` file is also present.

How should I handle this scenrio?

Comment: Can you add the relevant contents of your 2 .env files?

Comment: @N1ngu Apologies for the late reply. What i found out eventually is that when running unit test the.env.testing file takes precedence over .env.pipeline, or any other .env file.